# Change shipping cost in woocommerce, by product attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

In an woocommerce eshop I have the specific four categories
category_1, category_2, category_3 and category_4
and I want to change the shipping cost.
Specifically, when someone choose a product from the first 3 categories (category_1, category_2 and category_3), i want to change the shipping cost, by the product of the specific category.
When someone's choose a product from the category_1 the shopping cost will modify in 10, from the category_2 the shopping cost will modify in 10 and from category_3 the shopping cost will modify in 75.
But when someone choose a product from the last category (category_4), the shipping cost must modified by the product attribute 'size'.
The attribute 'size' has the values 'small', 'medium' and 'large'.
Specifically when someone's choose the 'small' size of a product the shipping cost will be 38, for 'medium' size the shipping cost will be 50 and for 'large' size will be 62.

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'change_shipping_cost', 10, 2 );
function change_shipping_cost( $rates, $package ) {

```
$shipping_method = 'flat_rate:11';


$categories = array( 'category_1', 'category_2', 'category_3', 'category_4' );


$max_quantity = 0;
foreach ( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
    if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $max_quantity = max( $max_quantity, $item['quantity'] );
    }
}

if ( isset( $rates[ $shipping_method ] ) ) {
    if ( $max_quantity == 1 ) {
        $max_cost = 0;
        $petbed_category_cost = array(
            'small' => 38,
            'medium' => 50,
            'large' => 62
        );
        foreach ( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
            if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
                if ( has_term( 'category_1', 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
                    $max_cost = max( $max_cost, 10 );
                }
                if( has_term ( 'category_2', 'product_cat', $item['product_id']) ){
                    $max_cost = max( $max_cost, 10 );
                }
                if (has_term ('category_3', 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ){
                    $max_cost = max( $max_cost, 75 );
                }
                if (has_term ('category_4', 'product_cat', $item['product_id'])){
                    $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );
                    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
                        $variation = wc_get_product( $item['variation_id'] );

                        if ( $variation ) {
                            $size = $variation->get_attribute('size');
                            if ( isset( $petbed_category_cost[ $size ] ) )
                            {
                                $max_cost = max( $max_cost, $petbed_category_cost[ $size ] );
                            }
                        }
                    } elseif ( $product ) {
                        $size = $product->get_attribute('size');
                        if ( isset( $petbed_category_cost[ $size ] ) ) {
                            $max_cost = max( $max_cost, $petbed_category_cost[ $size ] );
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }
        $rates[ $shipping_method ]->cost = $max_cost;
    }
    }
}

return $rates;
```

}

Created the above code. When someone's choose a product from the first three categories the shipping cost is changing. But when choose a product from category_4 with a specific attribute (for example 'medium'), the shipping cost does not display in eshop.
How can i solve this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `get_variation_attributes()` instead of `get_attribute()`, this should properly retrieve the 'size' attribute value for product variations in category_4 and modify the shipping cost accordingly.

`get_attribute()` method is used for getting custom product attributes, not for getting variations of product attributes.

https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/WC_Product_Variation::get_variation_attributes